# Why is Cloudflare changing my nameservers?

Tags: cloudflare, nameservers

I have a newbie question on nameservers @ cloudflare. All these while I have been using the nameservers below for my domains

ariella.ns.cloudflare.com
hugh.ns.cloudflare.com

But tonight when I added a new domain via runcloud and then another one via cloudflare, I was asked to change to new nameservers

Is this common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the nameserver combinations are unique to your account. So when you add them via runcloud, they will be different as runcloud has been assigned other nameservers by Cloudflare.

You can read more about the history of why they are 'names' here -

https://blog.cloudflare.com/whats-the-story-behind-the-names-of-cloudflares-name-servers/

Comment: Awww snap. How do I get the previous nameservers re-assigned to my account? Is there a way to do so? The thing is that I don’t have access to the domain management panel and thought the nameservers assigned are permanent.

Comment: What do you mean by domain management panel? Nameservers for a particular Cloudflare account are assigned at creation and never changed as far as I know. If you go to the "DNS" page in Cloudflare, and scroll down to the "Cloudflare Nameservers" section, it should specify the nameservers there. This should be the same for any domains on your account.

Once you bring a third party into the equation (like runcloud) however, all bets are off, as they can organize their Cloudflare accounts however they'd like (which would affect which nameservers are assigned).

Comment: I think the 2 new domains I tried to add to cloudflare last night have been compromised. I saw a bunch of unrecognizable DNS assigned to the domains and I believe Cloudflare gave them new nameservers due to them being spammy domains. I can prove this theory may be valid because when I add another domain (not the 2 affected ones), Cloudflare gave me my assigned nameservers. Thanks David for your help so far. I believe I got this now